# How to use "timers" in Visual Studio.NET 2008 to terminate a specific process

Tags: vb.net

How to terminate a process while it had take the CPU under its control

I am designing a project as a part of my study in college but my supervisor have no idea about the subject and he have no hope to help me.

so I have one chance to proceed, this chance is your site please help me.

Comment: Can you please revise your question so it makes sense? Your title is also full of typos and incorrect names.

Comment: Add more details about what you are specifically trying to do.  You simply want to kill a process?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but here is how to kill a process in VB.NET:

```
' get all processes by name
' where 'process_name' is the name of the process you want to kill
Dim arrProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name")

' kill all processes returned
For Each p As Process In arrProcess
    p.Kill() 
Next
```

You could put this as it's own `Sub` and call it when timer events are raised

See also: http://vbnetsample.blogspot.com/2007/08/start-and-kill-process.html

There are also a few questions here that cover process management in VB